# How do you set an Actor's "Render Custom Depth Pass" and "Depth Stencil Value" in C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In the Unreal 4.24 editor, in the "Rendering" section on an Actor's Detail panel, there's a checkbox for "Render CustomDepth Pass", and an integer for "CustomDepth Stencil Value". How do you set them in C++?

I've looked through the definition of AActor, and can't figure how these are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are not on the actor, but on each [Primitive Component](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/index.html). the details panel in the scene simply shows you the details for all the components that are on the actor.

You would change the component values in c++ by calling [SetRenderCustomDepth](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/SetRenderCustomDepth/index.html) and [SetCustomDepthStencilValue](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/SetCustomDepthStencilValue/index.html) on the component.